# How to locate/Access snackbar elements? I am not able to find locators for snackbar

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-snackbar

Android Automation using Appium: 
I am trying to verify/validate the snackbar. but Appium Inspector is not identifying the locators for snackbar. please help me how to validate the snackbar content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle it is to **check the source code of your Android application**. Assuming you have a text view and button in Snackbar, you should be able to find smth like this:

```
<view
    class="android.support.design.internal.SnackbarContentLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_text"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/snackbar_action"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</view>
```

If `id` is not in place, I suggest to add them by yourself.
Now you should be able to spot your snack bar, get the text or click the button:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 100).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
wait.until(visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("snackbar_text")));
```

Answer (score 2):

For Android-: Never use Appium inspector for inspecting Snackbar messages.

Even I faced this issue earlier then I used `UIAutomatorViewer` and I found both text and id for Snackbar messages.

**

for e.g-:

> resource id-:"vn.com.nitinsurange.mobile.uat:id/snackbar_text" text-: "Account number must be between 5 and 20 digits. (2142)"

**

```
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath ="//*[@value='Username']")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "vn.com.nitinsurange.mobile.uat:id/snackbar_text")
private MobileElement invalidpassword;
```

Hope it will useful for all.